# Kendo UI Grid Excel Export Unprintable Characters

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, export-to-excel

I'm using the Kendo UI Grid to display data imported from various 3rd party sources. When I use the Export To Excel functionality of the grid I am getting an error from Excel, it would appear that the grid is not formatting / handling non-printable characters correctly.

Error from Excel:
    Removed Part: /xl/sharedStrings.xml part with XML error.  (Strings) Illegal     xml character. Line 2, column 55298. Removed Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

The actual character at the column is:

[image: non-printable character screenshot]

Is there any way that I can get the grid to string non-printable characters on export, or would I be better trying to write a pre-parser when the data is loaded.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  How were you able to figure out the actual character at the indicates row/column? I thought I might try opening the .xlsx file in a text editor with a hope to seeing the xml structure, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Change the xlxs extension to zip, extract the contents of the archive and then search for the file and line number shown in the excel error message.